# How to fade out Vuetify v-data-table row

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a button in my v-data-table row that deletes the row. I'm using a typical splice which removes the row from the the array and the table row is deleted, just pops away and the row below jumps up.

```
markApproved(index, invoice) {
  this.invoices.splice(index, 1);
}
```

I'd like for Vuetify to fade the row out and slide the remaining rows up smoothly. How do I do this with Vuetify transitions?

Answer (score 0):

So... I don't have a full answer to your question but I'm hoping by sharing here that we can come to a complete solution.

other searches I have found out how to make v-data-table rows fade in and out... but... it is only the last row.

Using the standard vuetify table desserts:

```
      <v-data-table 
      :headers="headers" 
      :items="desserts">
        <template v-slot:body="{ items }">
          <tbody name="tr-fade" is="transition-group">
            <template>
              <tr
                v-for="(item, index) in items"
                :key="index"
                @click="desserts.splice(index,1)"
              >
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                <td>{{item.calories}}</td>
                <td>{{item.fat}}</td>
                <td>{{item.carbs}}</td>
                <td>{{item.protein}}</td>
                <td>{{item.iron}}</td>
              </tr>
            </template>
          </tbody>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
```

and some standard css transitions:

```
.tr-fade-enter-active,
.tr-fade-leave-active {
     transition: all 0.5s;
     }
.tr-fade-enter, .tr-fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ 
{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

This will get animations working in the data table... but the row that is actually animating is the last row.

demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/v-data-table-fade-row-uttwv

I think a hack-ish solution is possible by targeting the row directly in the DOM by using refs but haven't been able to try it out yet.

Comment: Yup, I love the effect.  Just have to figure out how to target the row of the clicked button.